# Pass a string from one class to another in java

Tags: java, string, class

I'm trying to pass a String from one class to another class but the result I'm getting is 'null'.  I want to pass the String username from LoginFrame to HomeworkFrame;

HomeworkFrame:

```
public void loadSubjects (){
    String item;
    try{
        System.out.println(username);
        Scanner f = new Scanner (new FileReader (username + " " + "Subjects" + ".txt"));
        while(f.hasNext()){
            item = f.nextLine();
            chSubjects.add(item);
        }
        f.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Subjects cannot be loaded!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

LoginFrame:

```
 public void loginUser(){
    r = new Registration();
    h = new HomeworkFrame();
    l = new Login();

    l.username = txtUser.getText();
    l.password = txtPass.getText();
    try{
        String line;
        boolean passwordFound = false ;
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(l.username + ".txt"));
        while((line = f.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.equals(l.password)){
                passwordFound = true;
            }
        }

        if(passwordFound){
                h.username = l.username;
                dispose();
                m.setSize(700,600);
                m.setLocation(100,100);
                m.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong information!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        f.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong information!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm getting the error "Subjects cannot be loaded" as the username is null(I checked it by using the println method).

Comment: Did you try to debug the code (e.g. with eclipse) and watch the variables getting passed around?

Comment: You have not shown the code where you call `loadSubjects()`. Please can you provide this?

Comment: 'public void loadSubjects (){
  
  String item;
  
  
  
  try{
   
   
   System.out.println(username);
   Scanner f = new Scanner (new FileReader (username + " " + "Subjects" + ".txt"));
   
   
   while(f.hasNext()){
    
    item = f.nextLine();
    chSubjects.add(item);
    
   }
   
   f.close(); 
  
  }catch(Exception e){
   
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Subjects cannot be loaded!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
 }'

Answer (score 1):

In case problems like this you have to track your variables/fields from the place you've noticed your 'username' field is null. Next steps should be:

1. Check what operations you do on 'h' object before you call the loadObjects() method and if any then check what influence they have on username field in HomeWorkFrame (using println or a debugger).
2. Check if your passwordFound in LoginFrame is true (because if it's false it doesn't assign a value to h.username)
3. If it's false check if your password's been retrieved from a file (using same println statement)

This kind of scenario should help you finding most of 'null' bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first, which type of Exception you get.

May be the file is not existing or the list is null or....

Answer (score 0):

Is a format problem : put a `\` before your space in pathString   : `"\ "`

You have to write it `"\ Subjects.txt"`, without '+' between.

Answer (score 0):

If **System.out.println(username); displays null** this means that

1.username variable is not initialized and left.

2.value is not assigned to it properly.

3.It might be a static variable and you are changing the value of it.

Please check all these conditions and please give that part of the code from where the **loadSubjects() is being called**, and not the body of that method as you have provioded it already.

**Also all those parts of code where the username is initialized,assigned,modified.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginFrame{

   private HomeworkFrame hw;

   public void doSomething(){

          String username = "your username";
          hw = new HomeworkFrame(username);
   }
}
public class HomeworkFrame{

   public HomeworkFrame(String username){

            doSomething with 'username'
   }
}
```

Ans to your question! :)

Answer (score -1):

It is required to specify or pass the value otherwise it will definitely give Null as it will not find any value to execute.